# Can we use IIFE (Immediately Invoked Function Expression) in class method

Tags: javascript

I tried below code to understand IIFE behaviour inside class methods.
Intrestingly I get undefined when I try to print the variable inside IIFE.

```
window.numValue=0;

class ArOps {
 constructor (){
   this.numValue = 0;
 }
 add(){
   this.numValue += 10;
   console.log(this.numValue);
   (function(){
     console.log(this.numValue);
   })();
 }
}

let arOps = new ArOps();

arOps.add();
```

[Even though window object contains the 'numValue' variable, console.log throws error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aE3Os.png)

```
window.numValue=0;

class ArOps {
 constructor (){
   this.numValue = 0;
 }
 add(){
   this.numValue += 10;
   console.log(this.numValue);
   (function(){
     console.log(this.numValue);
   }).call(window);
 }
}

let arOps = new ArOps();

arOps.add();
```

[But the same code refers to 'numValue' variable in window object when I assign 'window' inside call method.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iyECo.png)

Can anyone help me understand the reason for initial error?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please post your code as text not as images. See: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: Your problem is `this` has a different context inside `function`.

Comment: @charlietfl, Thank you for your suggestion. I have updated the question. Could you please explain bit more w.r.t 'this' having different context? Like where would the IIFE function refer to in the above example

Comment: Try using ES6 arrow function for the IIFE  ... `(()=> { console.log(this.numValue)})()`; An arrow function has no expicit `this` the way a standard `function` does

Comment: That's a not a great dupe target from @charlietfl. There *is* probably another answer that's a better fit. The primary issue is that es6 classes are executed in `strict` mode. As a result `this` does not default to the window object.